# Lower versions of php complaining about brackets. Why?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have been developing locally using Mamp, and everything was great until I uploaded to the server.  I have narrowed my problem down to having to do with the php version. Mamp was running on a newer version than the server.

If I run Mamp on PHP 5.6.2(or 5.5.X) I have no problems with my code. But if all I do is change the PHP version in Mamp preferences to PHP 5.3.29 if complains about the following line of code:

```
$shipping = reset($arrShipOptions['options'])[0]['price'];
```

The error is:

> syntax error, unexpected '['

First thing that came to mind was that reset() might be a new function. But according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php it was already available in PHP 4

Could an extra pair of eyes shed some light on this please.
Thanks

Comment: It's because of the array access! See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php it's for 5.4 and higher

Comment: Because `array dereferencing` wasn't available until [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: mark as duplicate but the reference link is ok?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam The PHP error reference addresses exactly this error at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22316776/541091

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older PHP versions you have to assign result from `reset` (or any other function) to variable and then access it using `[]`.

```
 $shipping = reset($arrShipOptions['options']);
 $shipping = $shipping[0]['price'];
```

Comment: Wow! I guess that was an easy question that just about everybody knew the answer to except me. Thanks for the help. +1 for being the quickest to answer. Will mark as correct when SO allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

before php 5.4 you cant chain syntax like that... 
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

It's called array dereferencing. It is not available in php 5.3

```
// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by using a feature available form **PHP 5.4+** called

> Function array dereferencing

Source http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php (*the third feature*)

The solution is breaking the code into two lines:

```
$shipping = reset($arrShipOptions['options']);
$shipping = $shipping[0]['price'];
```